# when reversing a Scan in HBase, which is the startKey and which is the stopKey?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I'm using HBase 0.98 which allows scans in reverse order.

Here is my code:

```
    scan = new Scan(eventTimeKey, nowKey);
    scan.setCaching(1); // setting this to 1 since I only want the first result
    scan.setMaxResultSize(1L);
    scan.addColumn(dataBytes, readingBytes);
    scan.setReversed(true);
    try {
        scanner = getTable().getScanner(scan);
        result = scanner.next();
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null)
            scanner.close();
    }
    if (result != null && valueIsZero(result))
        return true;
```

My question is, what order should the arguments to the Scan constructor be in?  Should startKey be 'aaa' and endKey be 'zzz' or the other way around?  Or does it matter?

**Update:** turns out, we have HBase 0.96 on the server side so reverse scans are, apparently, not going to work.  I think this explains the confusion I was having.  Until we upgrade, my tests are not going to be able to answer this question so I'll leave this open in case someone else is interested.

Comment: Turns out, the server I'm running against is on 0.96 so my reverse scans are, apparently, not going to work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of reversed scan in HBase 0.98 onwards start key and end key are reversed.

Documentation Link explains this: [Doc Link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4811)

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I won't be able to verify this answer until we upgrade our server to 0.98.  It might be as long as a month before I get to come back to this.  :(

Comment: Edited my answer. Actually its the other way around. Start key > end key.