# Bigtable Scan.setReversed() not working in version 1.2.1?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am using JAVA API to scan Bigtable by partial row-key, both backward and forward. This code works well, but ONLY forward:

```
    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.setReversed(true);    
    s.setStartRow(rowKey);          
    s.setStopRow(rowKeyEnd); 
    ResultScanner scanner = tbl.getScanner(s);
    for (Result row : scanner)
    {   
        String rk = new String(row.getRow());
        System.out.println("Row: " + rk);
    }
```

It seems like the line `.setReversed(true);` does not have any impact on its own, regardless of whether I set it before or after setting the start and end row-keys. If I switch start and end row keys in `.setStartRow()` and `.setStopRow()`, then I get an Exception in the iteration code `(Result row : scanner)`:
*Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error in field 'row_ranges' : Error in element #0 : start_key must be less than end_key*

As I understand from this discussion [when reversing a Scan in HBase, which is the startKey and which is the stopKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390546/when-reversing-a-scan-in-hbase-which-is-the-startkey-and-which-is-the-stopkey), the Reverse Scan doesn't work in versions below 0.98, but I see my server-side version as 1.2.1 in Google Cloud Console:

hbase(main):023:0> version
1.2.1, r8d8a7107dc4ccbf36a92f64675dc60392f85c015, Wed Mar 30 11:29:35 CDT 2016

Also, my client-side JAR is bigtable-hbase-1.2-0.9.4.jar

My row-keys are formatted in the following fashion, as a test:
John*1*XXX
John*2*XXX
John*3*XXX
Is there a better way to get this done please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Bigtable does not support reverse scanning](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-differences#gets_and_scans).  The HBase API mostly lines up with Cloud Bigtable, but not all.  You found one of the missing features in Bigtable.

Comment: Thanks helpful post. I gather from the post that Coprocessors are not supported either. I had a related question on how to get a row count of the returned scan, which seems to involve the Coprocessor API here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183912/aggregationclient-rowcount-in-bigtable-api-cant-get-it-to-work]. I suppose I can't rely on that either?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse scans are now available in [Preview](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reads#reverse-scan).